# How to design Login use MVVM+Databinding in android studio?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-databinding

I am a newcomer and have no programming experience. Now I use CODELABS.developer.google.com and developer.android.com to learn java +android, but I have encountered problems when designing the "login" module. This problem has taken me 3 days. I search for solutions on Google every day, but I still haven't solved it.

Error:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\exmaple\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\exmaple\databinding\FragmentEmailEditBinding.java:15: ����: �Ҳ�������
import com.exmaple.ViewModel;
                  ^
  ����:   �� ViewModel
  λ��: ����� com.exmaple

C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\exmaple\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\exmaple\databinding\FragmentEmailEditBinding.java:33: ����: �����ViewModel.Login������
  protected ViewModel.Login.EmailAuthViewModel mEmailAuthViewModel;
                           ^
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        FragmentEmailEditBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.fragment_email_edit);
        EmailAuthViewModel emailAuthViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(EmailAuthViewModel.class);
        binding.getEmailAuthViewModel();
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        EmailAuthFragment emailAuthFragment = new EmailAuthFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frag_signIn,emailAuthFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

fragment_email_edit.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="emailAuthViewModel"
            type="com.example.ViewModel.Login.EmailAuthViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fieldEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:text="@={emailAuthViewModel.email}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fieldPassword"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fieldPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:text="@{emailAuthViewModel.password}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fieldEmail"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

EmailAuthViewModel.java

```
public class EmailAuthViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public MutableLiveData<String> email = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> password = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public EmailAuthViewModel(MutableLiveData<String> email, MutableLiveData<String> password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

EmailAuthModel.java

```
class EmailAuthModel {

}
```

Comment: I’m going to crash.. because the error is completely garbled. I don’t know where the problem is in the VIEWMODEL file. I even deleted all the code in the MODEL, but the problem still exists, and I can’t even open AVD

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that this line `binding.getEmailAuthViewModel();`
 throws NPE since you didn't pass the viewmodel to binding anywhere. I think you want to pass viewmodel to databinding file, not get from it.

Comment: I saw the getter and setter set in the viewmodel in the video of YOUTUBE, so I filled them in VIEWMODEL.

Comment: problem in here, 3 error command lines will locate the error in the generated file mEmailAuthViewModel,getEmailAuthViewModel(), setEmailAuthViewModel(). But I cannot change the automatically generated file, how should I correct the error?

Comment: Through learning, I learned that VM is the transfer between VIEW and MODEL, which is responsible for operating and obtaining UI information. So, shouldn't we put getters and setters in the viewmodel folder?

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't understand what you are saying :/

Comment: Im sorry .How should I set up the viewmodel file to resolve binding.getEmailAuthViewModel();

Answer (score 0):

Did you try renaming your package "ViewModel" to "viewmodel"? Because "ViewModel" is the name of one of the default classes.

And I also found a strangeness in your package, In the error "com.exmaple" but in your layout file use "com.example".